# Live HTTP headers add-on

Tags: http-headers, firefox-addon, mobile-website

I need to use the Live HTTP Headers add-on to view request headers and confirm that they match the samples from actual mobile devices, i installed this add-on in firefox but don't know where exactly it provides this feature. I also tried double-clicking on **HTTP Headers** as shown in the figure below, but nothing appears.
 [image]

Comment: Start navigating web pages and headers will populate here.

Answer (score 0):

use google chrome dev toolbar , in chrome browser press F12 -> got to network tab -> select your request url -> header tab